# Is "since the prior night" correct grammar?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

I am writing a paper, and am unsure about the following phrase:

> "dirty diapers she has been sitting in since the prior night"

Specifically, I am unsure about "since the prior night".  Is this an acceptable phrase?

Comment: Is the phrase you provided here an entire sentence, or part of a larger sentence?  If it's part of a larger sentence, could you please provide the entire sentence?  Also: what about "since the prior night" makes you uncertain about it?  Please explain your thoughts.

Comment: The sentence above is part of a larger sentence. this is the whole sentence: "In the mornings when Aibleen arrives to work she changes Mae Mobley’s dirty diapers that she has been sitting in since the prior night.". I am uncertain because when I keep reading it over it sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Since this is a paper that you're writing, could you comment on why you chose '_prior_' instead of '_previous_' or even a simple '_yesterday_' (If this was part of an ongoing dialog between two characters)?

Comment: I was originally using previous but I just wanted to use a different word.

Comment: A more idiomatic different wording would be *... since the night before.*.

Answer (score 1):

"Since the prior night" sounds stilted in this sentence.

Some expressions to make the sentence sound more fluent could be:

> "...dirty diapers she has been sitting in **all** [of last] **night**"

> "...dirty diapers she has been sitting in **since the night before**"

I personally think that the first of the two may be better for what you are does looking for.  Although simple, it does seem to convey properly what you want to say.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your help!